# Undeclared Variable in Function Call c++

Tags: c++, function, variables

I'm working in Visual Studio on a C++ program, and am creating a function to produce a distance using input. My code looks something like this:

```
double distancCalc(lat2, long2)
{
    //do math calculation with output
}
```

The problem I am having is that the variables lat2 and long2 are undefined variables. My prof doesn't want us using global variables, so I don't know how I am supposed to define these variables, which will be input from the main function, without using a global variable.

Comment: See about [declare function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)

Comment: After fixing the prototype of the function, see answers below, you can call this function in your main `distanceCalc(100, 100)`

Answer (score 1):

See if this gets you anywhere useful:

```
double distancCalc (double lat2, double long2)
{
    ....
}
```

Depending on the intent of the function, you might prefer this:

```
double distancCalc (double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am just really tired, because I realized how to solve this after I asked the question. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @EmilyKelly:  I updated my answer with more of what you might be missing.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a return type and two parameter names but have not specified the parameter types.

```
double distanceCalc(lat2, long2)
^^1^^^              ^2^^  ^^3^^
{
   ... code ...
}
```

1. Is a type without a name
2. Is a name without a **type**
3. Is a name without a **type**

You probably intended to do something like this:

```
double distanceCalc(double lat2, double long2)
{
    ... code ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Default Arguments

I'm rusty on C++, but I know you can explicity declare variables as arguments called **default arguments**:

## Example

```
double distancCalc(int lat2 = 0, int long2 = 0)
{
    //do math calculation with output
}
```

Just like declaring variables, you do them in the function header. It is optional to explicitly give the variables a value as well.